# Chrome Web Store Manifest

Tags: chrome-web-store, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I developed my gmail gadget to find sender email and add it to database .Hopefully I was able to see my gadget at bottom of email, and also I able to call my web Api from google.I created chrome web store app. I did some part and it works fine now. But I want to know exactly which steps I have to follow to do that?

here's my gadget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>`enter code here`
  <ModulePrefs title="Test Gadget"
    description=""
    height="20"
    author="excendia"
    author_email="..."
    author_location="">

    <!-- Declare feature dependencies. -->

    <!-- This one is not specific to Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>

    <!-- The next feature, Caja, is optional, and is supported for
     use only within test domains. Uncomment the tag only for
     non-production gadgets. -->
    <!-- <Require feature="caja"/> -->

    <!-- The next feature, google.contentmatch, is required for all
     Gmail contextual gadgets.
     <Param> - specify one or more comma-separated extractor IDs in
     a param named "extractors". This line is overridden by the extractor ID
     in the manifest, but is still expected to be present. -->
    <Require feature="google.contentmatch">
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:MessageIDExtractor
      </Param>
    </Require>

  </ModulePrefs>

  <!-- Define the content type and display location. The settings
   "html" and "card" are required for all Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
  <Content type="html" view="card">
    <![CDATA[
      <script type="text/javascript">

        <!-- Fetch the array of content matches. -->
        matches = google.contentmatch.getContentMatches();
        var matchList = document.createElement('UL');
        var listItem;
        var extractedText;

        <!-- Iterate through the array and display output for each match. -->
        for (var match in matches) {
          for (var key in matches[match]) {
            listItem = document.createElement('LI');
            extractedText = document.createTextNode(key + ": " + matches[match][key]);
            listItem.appendChild(extractedText);
            matchList.appendChild(listItem);
          }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(matchList);
        gadgets.window.adjustHeight(100);
      </script>
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find steps to create chrome web store [here](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing).